# Issues initializing specific rows and columns in a 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a two dimensional arra, and two 1d Arrays.

I need to take the elements from the 1st 1d array and store them in the the first 5 rows and columns of the the 2d array.

I then need to take the elements from the second 1d array and store them in the remaining rows and columns of the 2d array.

The issue is that the elements aren't going in correctly, please see the output at the bottom to understand what I mean!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int ROWS = 10; 
const int COLUMNS = 4;

void CopyArrays(int Array1[], int a1_Size, int Array2[], int a2_Size, int Array3[][COLUMNS]);

/* Array1[] refers to array1 a1_Size refers to the size of the first array, 
   Array2 refers to array2 and a2_Size refers to the size of array2, 
   And Array3[][COLUMNS] refers to the 2d array */


void DisplayArray3(int Array3[][COLUMNS]);

int main()
{
  int array1[20] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

  int array2[20] = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40};

  int Array3[ROWS][COLUMNS];

  CopyArrays(array1, 20, array2, 20, Array3);

  DisplayArray3(Array3);       

  return 0;
}

void CopyArrays(int Array1[], int a1_Size, int Array2[], int a2_Size, int Array3[][COLUMNS])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < a1_Size; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++)
       {
          for (int k = i; k < COLUMNS; k++)
          {
             Array3[j][k] = Array1[i];
          }
       }
    } 

}


void DisplayArray3(int Array3[][COLUMNS])
{ 
      for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
      { 
           for(int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
           {    
              cout << setw(10) << Array3[i][j];
           } 
        cout << "\n" ;
      } 
}
```

// Output:

```
     1         2         3         4
     1         2         3         4
     1         2         3         4
     1         2         3         4
     1         2         3         4
     1         2         3         4
     1         2         3         4
     1         2         3         4
     1         2         3         4
     1         2         3         4
```

So as you can see only the first four elements from the array alpha are being put into the Array3 Instead of 1 - 20. Some where my logic is flawed but I'm not sure how to correct it.

Any suggestions?

PS: I realize the for loops can be condensed and I plan on doing so, also I didn't set the for loops to end the processing at row 5 because at this point I'm more concerned with number range being correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three nested loops is not the way to do this. This might work:

```
void CopyArrays(int Array1[], int a1_Size, int Array2[], int a2_Size, int Array3[][COLUMNS])
{
    int i = 0;

    for ( ; i < a1_Size; i++)
        // indexing a 2D array with one variable
        Array3[i / COLUMNS][i % COLUMNS] = Array1[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < a2_Size; j++)
        Array3[(j + i) / COLUMNS][(j + i) % COLUMNS] = Array2[j];
}
```

I used `(j + i)` to continue in writing `Array3`'s elements after where the first loop left off.

Comment: Oh wow I was completely off base, this makes sense though thank you for the response it did solve the issue. I'm finding multi dimensional arrays to be a pain in the ass lol.